# phonegap 3.3 iOS Facebook Connect redirect_uri must be absolute

Tags: iphone, facebook, phonegap-plugins

I am developing ios native application using phonegap. This application has barcodescanner and facebook connect features. I am using phonegap version 2.9.0.

The user has to login with facebook credentials when the application is launched. There is a button in the application and it will redirect to browser (safari) for asking facebook login when the button is clicked. Also, this application has facebook post feature.

It was working fine (facebook connect and barcodescanner) with phonegap version 2.9.0.

Now, facebook connect (for login) is not working after I upgrade phonegap version 3.3.0.
It says "redirect_uri must be absolute" after the browser (safari) is launched.

I am using [this link](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect). After I upgrade the phonegap version to 3.3.0, I did not change my application logic. I am using following code for facebook initialize and facebook login when the button is clicked.

Facebook init.

```
FB.init({ appId: "<appid>", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });
```

Facebook login

```
FB.login(function(response){},{scope:"email"});
```

I tried changing the appid also, Same response.

I have included JS files for phonegap framework and facebook connect framework and they are loaded when the application is loaded. I am sure about it. There are no errors while building the app.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

--Sridhar

Comment: Did you manage to figure out what is happening? I am having the same problem now on the iOS simulator.

Answer (score 0):

redirect_uri errors usually  raise if you don't give the same link the one u used while creating FB app on developers page something like below. [image]

Don't use redirect_uri in initializing or methods just add in developers page FB app. That should work.

Comment: The problem is not with facebook app and problem is with phonegap 3.3.0. The same application logic was working fine with phonegap 2.9.0. I did not change anything (neither application logic nor facebook app settings) after I upgrade phonegap version to 3.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://github.com/mallzee/phonegap-facebook-plugin) could be helpfull.

but, I can't make it work the auto install

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/mallzee/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable APP_ID="[FB APP ID]" --variable APP_NAME="[FB APP NAME]"
```

it said to my: [error] Variable(s) missing: APP_ID, APP_NAME

Comment: I have used this command to install this plugin to my project. I am facing issue after installing this plugin.

Comment: how you make it to use the command? i used like this: phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/mallzee/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable APP_ID="1234567890" --variable APP_NAME="appname"  but this doesn't.

Comment: i'm still facing the same problem, have u consider downgrade to 2.9 (i made it and still without make it work)

Comment: I have downloaded this plugin to my local, remove preferences lines from plugin.xml and install this plugin from local. No need to downgrade for installing this plugin.

Comment: I make it work with phonegap 3.3 but after init, it disabled others plugins (like inappbrowser), when i find the solutions, i'll post it for you

Comment: how could you do it? maybe, I can do the same and find why other plugins were disabled

Comment: Well, i follow all the [step by step](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

Comment: Well, i follow all the [step by step](https://github.com/mallzee/phonegap-facebook-plugin). After it, i change the new pg-plugin-fb-connect.js for the old cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js. And then start working, but after de cordova.exec of this file, the cordova.exec stop working. try everything, but it happend to me also with the [socialShare plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin). After all, i just takeout the social login, but still trying to fix socialshare. If you have any idea let me know

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me. Apparently cordova failed to copy the APP_ID and APP_NAME variables from the plugin config into the .plist so I had to go in and edit the .plist file that cordova build generates with the value of the variables.

Under `platform/ios/<appname>/<appname>-Info.plist` search for $APP_ID and $APP_NAME in that file, and replace them with their values.

After doing that the login worked normally.